# Foreach implementation in C++, a Poor man's approach

Tags: c++

There are happy people working with boost and Qt. In my current "embedded" project I have to use home-made container classes. OK, enough complaining.

I've tried to implement an easy and self-contained foreach like that:

```
#define ForEachString(S,C) TString S;\
        for ( int i=0; i<C.GetSize() && (!!(&(S=C[i]))); ++i  )
```

It iterates through a string-list which has op[] and GetSize() methods. E.g.:

```
TStringList tables;
ForEachString( table, tables )
{
  //do sth. with tab.
}
```

Of cause, the ugly thing is, each container type requires its own macro. 
Therefore my question: Is it possible to do it container independant and still self contained (all required stuff **within** the macro definition)?

Regards,
Valentin

Comment: The answer is "yes", and the explanation can be found [here](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html).

Comment: Just follow STL-like method names.

Comment: Don't do it, it's not standard and it doesn't help readability much, and can hide issues like duplicate definitions

Comment: Could you use BOOST_FOREACH, with a template wrapper around your custom container (parameterized on the element type) that has `begin/end` functions returning an iterator that you write?

Comment: @Johannes: I know this. The foreach macros in this article require many template helpers helping to discover the type. I was hoping it could be possible to do it in one line :-(

Comment: Your condition doesn't seem to make sense. Why do you test the address of the element? Have you overloaded the unary `&` operator in a nasty way?

Comment: @Johannes: he isn't really testing the address of the element, he's assigning to `S` in his condition, and then doing something somewhat convoluted to get a "true" result.

Comment: @Steve well I'm doing the healthy assumption that `A = B` returns `A&`. I'm not surewhat `&(A = B)` would be, if not taking its address. I'm prepared to being told about insane semantics by know, though.

Comment: @Johannes: yes, taking the address, but the only property of that address that's used is that it's non-null (unless, as you say, there's some shameful operator overloading going on). Not sure what the `!!` adds, but I thought the whole `!!(&` business is just to transform `TString&` to get a boolean for `&&`. Maybe `(S = C[i], true)` hasn't occurred.

Comment: @Steve OK that explains its purpose. I didn't think of that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you could parameterise on the type T:

```
#define ForEach(T,S,C) T S;\ 
    for ( int i=0; i<C.GetSize() && (!!(&(S=C[i]))); ++i  ) 

TStringList tables; 
ForEach( TString, table, tables ) 
{ 
  //do sth. with tab. 
}
```

Comment: OK, seems to be the most pragmatic approach.

Comment: This is not a single expression, as Talagrand points out. Use `#define ForEach(T,S,C) for (T S, int i=0; i<C.GetSize() && (!!(&(S=C[i]))); ++i)`

Comment: Meh, [BOOST_FOREACH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339589/foreach-implementation-in-c-a-poor-mans-approach/4339813#4339813) is cooler, since it avoids an unnecessary parameter.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend this one

```
#define ForEachString(S,C) \
  if(bool _j_ = false) ; else
    for (int _i_ = 0; _i_ < C.GetSize() && !_j_; ++_i_, _j_ = !_j_)
      for(S = C[_i_]; !_j_; _j_ = true)

TStringList tables;
ForEachString(TString table, tables)
{
  //do sth. with table
}
```

The weird actions with `_j_` are needed to not break `break` inside the loop. Best use names like `_i_` and `_j_` so to not interfere with user's local loop variables.

Comment: Is the second for loop only for getting next value into S? Indeed it seems to be a better solution, since (!!(&(S=C[i]))) could return false if container contained pointers and if 0-pointers were valid. In this case the iteration would stop :-(  (In my case op[] returns const refs. so I didn't consider this scenario first)

Answer (score 2):

Your macro is dangerous. Consider:

```
if (<condition>)
    ForEachString(table, tables)
    {
        // do something
    }
```

Also, S is put into the enclosing scope. So you can't have two ForEachString calls in the same block.

If you have a bleeding-edge compiler, [range-based for-loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Range-based_for-loop) are part of C++0x

Again, with C++0x, you could replace `TString S;` with `decltype(C[0]) S;`

Or, just make the type part of the macro:

```
#define ForEachString(T, S, C) T S; ...
```

Comment: Thank you for hints. However yoer example causes compilation error, so is not that dangerous. Two 'foreach' in same scope would go, if first parameters had different names. Unfortanutely, c++0x is not used in the project.

Answer (score 2):

The Boost libraries have an implementation of a foreach-like macro called BOOST_FOREACH which does just this.  It's container-independent and can also work on raw arrays and C-style strings.  The implementation is nothing short of terrifying (lots of crazy template machinery for type introspection), but the net result is fast, lean, mean, and widely-used.  You can find more information about this [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/foreach.html).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MY_CONTAINER(a, b) a b; \
    typedef a::iterator b##_itr;
#define for_each(itr, a)  for(a##_itr itr = a.begin(); itr != a.end(); ++itr) 

MY_CONTAINER(vector<int>, vnVec);
vnVec.push_back(2);
vnVec.push_back(3);
vnVec.push_back(10);

for_each(itr, vnVec)
  cout << *itr << endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

If your goal in creating this macro is to learn, I recommend you read Eric Niebler's explanation of how to implement foreach, pointed to by Johannes Schaub - litb  ([this](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html)).  It goes into detail about all the pitfalls one encounters when trying to solve this problem.

If your main concern is to just get a working foreach Macro, the function is documented and submitted to Boost by Eric Niebler as [`BOOST_FOREACH`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/foreach.html) .

Community wiki, since I'm just repeating what Johannes said.

Comment: -1: Please read first. Boost "can't" be used in many projects (e.g. many automotive). The most official reason is, it is not stable. I suspect the real reason is, many project leaders are not familiar enough with boost.